# Impala create external table, stored by Hive

Tags: twitter, hbase, flume, impala, flume-ng

I am trying to figure out since yesterday why my table creation is not working. Since I can't link my Impala to my Hbase I can't make queries on my twitter stream :/

Do I need a special JAR like Hive for the SerDe properties ?

Here is my command:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HB_IMPALA_TWEETS (
>   id int,
>   id_str string,
>   text string,
>   created_at timestamp,
>   geo_latitude double,
>   geo_longitude double,
>   user_screen_name string,
>   user_location string,
>   user_followers_count string,
>   user_profile_image_url string
>   )
>   STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
>   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
>   "hbase.columns.mapping" =
>   ":key,tweet:id_str,tweet:text,tweet:created_at,tweet:geo_latitude,tweet:geo_longitude, user:screen_name,user:location,user:followers_count,user:profile_image_url"
>   )
>   TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "tweets");

But I got an error on: the strored by:

Query: create EXTERNAL TABLE HB_IMPALA_TWEETS ( id int, id_str string, text string, created_at timestamp, geo_latitude double, geo_longitude double, user_screen_name string, user_location string, user_followers_count string, user_profile_image_url string ) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,tweet:id_str,tweet:text,tweet:created_at,tweet:geo_latitude,tweet:geo_longitude, user:screen_name,user:location,user:followers_count,user:profile_image_url" ) TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "tweets")
ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
...image_url string ) STORED **BY** 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.h...

Encountered: BY

Expected: AS

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

For info, I followed this page:
https://github.com/AronMacDonald/Twitter_Hbase_Impala/blob/master/README.md

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that Impala still not support the SerDe (serialization/deserialisation).

> "You create the tables on the Impala side using the Hive shell,
>   because the Impala CREATE TABLE statement currently does not support
>   custom SerDes and some other syntax needed for these tables: You
>   designate it as an HBase table using the STORED BY
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' clause on the Hive
>   CREATE TABLE statement."

So, just run the command on the hive shell, or hue hive, then, in impala, type 'invalidate metadata', and then you can see your table with a 'show tables'.

So for this part the problem seems solved.